# Android (x86) USB on PC "This is not a bootable disk"

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, android-x86

**TL;DR**: I installed Android x86 on USB with main HDD detached. Now whenever I want to use that Android on USB, I have to detach HDD, else USB doesn't boot & says `This is not a bootable device`. I want to use Android while main HDD is still connected. Thanks.

**Long story:**

I installed Android x86 (LineageOS) on a USB flash drive, but before doing that, I had manually removed the computer's main Hard Drive. The USB drive was the only drive attached to the PC then (other than empty CD drive). Installation of Android worked OK, everything worked great, Android operated fine, etc. Then I reverted my system back to normal state, by removing the Android USB, and replaced my original HDD in the system, which now operates as normal with original OS in it (Windows).

Now the issue is that if I want to use Android again via that USB, it will only boot if that USB is the only one attached to the PC. That means I have to manually remove the HDD every time. If I keep the HDD in and boot the machine via USB (computer's boot device chooser menu via F12) there's an error `This is not a bootable device`.

So I would like to use Android in that USB while the main HDD is still attached. How should I do that (without having to reinstall Android LineageOS elsewhere as I have things stored in it and I have spent quite some time tweaking many settings and customizations etc)

**Additional info (if useful)**: When I read the Android USB in Windows, it shows up as a drive labelled 'EFI' which has the following in the root:

```
\boot
\efi
\LOST.DIR
\Android
BOOTEX.LOG
startup.nsh
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try this : https://itsfoss.com/no-bootable-device-found-ubuntu/

Comment: Are you maybe trying to legacy (MBR) boot from the USB instead of EFI booting from it?

Comment: @user52599 Does that work for USB installs too?

Comment: @User025 How do I find out? (Will the dir structure I noted above tell me?)

Comment: @spcsLrg Yes it will .

Comment: When you press F12 when you computer starts, you get a list of devices to boot from. When the name is the name of the actual hardware (something like WDBWLG0040HBK-EESN for example) then it normally means you are legacy booting. EFI devices have normally some descriptive name like "Windows Boot Manager". Some computers also group devices by legacy / EFI boot. A picture of your PCs boot menu would be helpful. @spcsLrg

Comment: @User025 Boot menu shows it as generic  `USB HDD: Mass Storage Device` 
 , the other devices there do have proper names e.g. `ATA HDD0: HITACHI ABCD1234`  &  `ATAPI CD0: HL-DT-STABCD1234`  &  `Windows Boot Manager` etc. So you're right I think that USB's EFI entry is missing perhaps?

Comment: It seems like that, I once had that problem when using a tool from Acronis to create my USB, I then used the tool "Rufus" with an iso from Acronis and after that it showed up as EFI device

Comment: @user52599 Unfortunately my PC, not Acer, doesn't have any options like that in the BIOS menu. However, do you think I'm closer to identifying the [problem here](https://superuser.com/questions/1518708/android-x86-usb-on-pc-this-is-not-a-bootable-disk#comment2299410_1518708)  ? Thank you.

Comment: @User025 Any thoughts on how should I proceed with my particular case (or what should I search for) now? Thank you very much!

Comment: Well since it works with your HDD disconnected, it seems like the USB is formatted correctly. However for whatever reason your PC doesn't allow you to EFI boot from it via boot menu. Since every BIOS / UEFI is different I can't tell you why that is, maybe try disabling secure boot temporarily or look for any setting in your Bios that might affect USB boot

Comment: @User025 My computer does not support Secure Boot at all, so I guess I'll have to wait or search for another solution... Thank you for your pointers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I finally fixed it:

I have [Grub2Win](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/) now installed as my computer's boot manager.  So all I had to do

1. Labelled the Android partition on the USB as *Android-x86* (Not the EFI partition on USB, Android partition on USB is the hidden one with the folder `/cm-x86-14.1-r3/`, you can scan and see all available partitions and folders to the PC via Grub2Win's boot menu)
2. Opened Grub2Win under Windows, added a new boot entry, with:

Type: `Custom code` Title: `Android x86 LineageOS` Code:

```
set partlabel=Android-x86
getbootpartition  label  $partlabel
linux /cm-x86-14.1-r3/kernel root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.selinux=permissive buildvariant=userdebug
initrd  /cm-x86-14.1-r3/initrd.img
```

Now when computer boots with Android USB attached and main HDD connected too, there's an additional menu item in Grub2Win called *Android x86 LineageOS* and selecting it boots Android fine.